# Ubuntu - Automagically import and rename iPhone photos/videos

Tags: ubuntu, iphone, photos

I've been using Shotwell to import my iPhone photos, however, Shotwell itself can't:
1) Auto import upon mount
2) Rename imported photos and videos

After snooping around, I found Rapid Photo Downloader, which should work the way I want, however it cant read from a mounted iPhone.

Is there any way around this? I basically only want to auto import all photos and videos upon mount and rename files with their exif data, put the files in separate folders and subfolders.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am the developer of Rapid Photo Downloader. Version 0.9.x downloads from smartphones. Any earlier version will not work with smartphones.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly what I am looking for but I think it works.